# Can I use Eloquent to order a collection of children by a property of their parents?

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a thing class:

```
class Thing extends Eloquent
{
    public function owner() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Owner');
    }
}
```

And an owner class:

```
class Owner extends Eloquent
{
    public function things() {
        return $this->hasMany('Thing');
    }
}
```

I am getting a paginated list of Things ordered by some property of the thing like this:

```
Thing::orderBy('thing_property')->paginate(20);
```

But I realized I would like to get the list of things ordered by a property of their owners instead.  Is there an Eloquent way to do this?  I have tried a lot of different things with no success.  I should probably include some things I've tried in my question, but there are a lot of them, most of them are probably dumb, and I can't really even get a good idea of whether any of them are even close.  The most recent one was:

```
Thing::with('owner')->orderBy('owner.owner_property')->paginate(20);
```

After that not working and reading more about it, I see this is not how 'with()' should be used.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to find anything about what I should be using instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join owner's table. Eager loading (`with`) doesn't join but runs another query for the related models.

```
$things = Thing::join('owners', 'owners.id', '=', 'things.owner_id')
              ->orderBy('owners.owner_property')
              ->get(['things.*']); // return only columns from things
```

Should you have any `Thing` rows without `Owner` (owner_id = null), use `leftJoin` instead of `join`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you have a good basic grasp on Laravels Eloquent ORM.

I would suggest the following if you wanted to get `things` with the order based upon their parent `owner`:

```
$results = Owner::with('things')
    ->orderBy('owner_property', 'ASC')
    ->paginate(20);
```

Or if you would like to order the parent `owner` and then the children `things`, you could do the following:

```
$results = Owner::with(array( 'things' => 
    function($query){
        $query->orderBy('things_property', 'DESC');
    })
    ->orderBy('owner_property', 'ASC')
    ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: @ThomasAndrews my solution will return a collection of Owners which would also have a things property that you could iterate over. However as deczo pointed out, Laravel does this by executing two queries - his solution is tidier and does exactly what you want :)